# Manipulate text file from the command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

With this command

```
dir "directory" / s / b> c: \ file.txt
```

I save all files in a given directory to a text file that formatting

```
C:\Full Name
```

But how to list files with the same extension (.wav) and save with this formatting?

```
?C:\Full Name.wav
```

If this is possible of course.

Comment: dir "directory" /b /s should give the file names with extensions. Do you want it to list files matching a particular extension only ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### dir syntax errors

You are using the command:

```
dir "directory" / s / b> c: \ file.txt
```

You cannot have spaces between the **parts** of a **filename**, so `c: \ file.txt` should be `c:\file.txt`.

If `filename` contains spaces it should be quoted, eg `"c:\filename with space.txt"`.

Although not required it is normal to not have a <kbd>space</kbd> after the <kbd>/</kbd> that specifies a command option. So your command should be something like:

```
dir "directory" /s /b > c:\file.txt
```

---

#### How do I get a list of files (`.wav`) and save with this formatting?

```
?C:\Full Name.wav
```

Use the following command:

```
dir "directory\*.wav" /s /b >> c:\file.txt
```

If you wish to prefix the name with `?` (as per your example), then use the following command:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %a in (`dir /b /s "directory\*.wav"')  do echo ?%a >> c:\file.txt
```

Notes:

- To use the previous command in a batch file replace each `%` with `%%`.
- In the `for /f` command use `>> c:\file.txt` instead of `> c:\file.txt` to append instead of overwriting the output each time through the loop.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.

Comment: Thank you for responding. But I see that the data is overwritten leaving only the last line of the loop in the C: \ file.txt. How to work around this?

Comment: @CaitanoOliveira Answer updated to prevent overwriting of data when using `for /f`

Comment: Thank you, almost everything works well, now I'm having trouble with long file names.
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Mid\FileTest.exe`
output is
`C:\Program`
How to get around this ?

Comment: @CaitanoOliveira `for /f` answer updated to work with file/directory names containing a space

Comment: It all worked here, I am grateful for the information which gave me.

Answer (score 1):

(You will probably need to Run 'cmd' as Admin to save in the c: drive)

```
DIR [drive:][path][*.wav] /s/b >c:\file.txt
```